# How to use an object passed to a fun as context for inner function?

Tags: javascript, this

I am iterating through an array of functions and am suppose to call each function USING THE OBJECT AS THE CONTEXT  and I don't know how to do it - tried apply but it doesn't work-I guess because I don't fully understand this, apply etc.
Happy about some help!

```
function calling(obj,arr){
 for (var i=0; i<arr.length;i++){
  arr[i].apply(null,obj);
   }
 return arr;
}

    var fnA = [
        function () {
            this.yes = true;
        },
        function () {
            this.no = false;
        }
    ];
    var obj = {};

    calling(obj, fnA);
    obj.yes; //should return true
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure you read [the documentation of `Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) correctly?

`thisArg`, which sets the execution context, is the first parameter of `apply`, not the second:

```
arr[i].apply(obj);
```

As second parameter, you can optionally pass an array of arguments that the function should be called with.

Answer (score 0):

This is example using recursion approach.
If your array of functions should be immutable you need a For loop instead of recursion (or make a copy of initial array).

```
var functions = [
    function() { this.yes = true; },
    function() { this.no = false; }
];

var emptyObject = {};

function delegate(object, methods) {
    if (methods.length) {
        methods.splice(0, 1)[0].apply(object);
        delegate(object, methods);
    }
}

delegate(emptyObject, functions);

console.log(emptyObject.yes);
console.log(emptyObject.no);
```